# Matrix with outer elements keep visual consistency

Tags: math-mode

I am tying to figure out what is the best method to write a matrix with outer elements in the first row and column. Below is the code using `array` `blkarray` and `kbordermatrix` packages.

As it can be seen, the `[]` in `blkarray` does not expand as in `\left[ \right]` when using `array`. Also the visual appearance of `kbordermatrix` is somehow different from the `array`. On the other hand, with `array` I am not able to get the outer indexes.

I would prefer to use something based on `array` to keep the visual consistency throughout the document or change `blkarray` / `kbordermatrix` so that a similar result can be achieved.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    P =
    \begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
               & BS_1    & BS_2    & \ldots & BS_B    \\ 
    \begin{block}{c[cccc]}
        UE_1   & P_{1,1} & P_{1,2} & \ldots & P_{1,B} \\
        UE_2   & P_{2,1} & P_{2,2} & \ldots & P_{1,B} \\
        \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
        UE_U   & P_{U,1} & P_{U,2} & \ldots & P_{U,B} \\
    \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    P = \left[
    \begin{array}{c|cccc}
               & BS_1    & BS_2    & \ldots & BS_B    \\ \hline
        UE_1   & P_{1,1} & P_{1,2} & \ldots & P_{1,B} \\
        UE_2   & P_{2,1} & P_{2,2} & \ldots & P_{1,B} \\
        \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
        UE_U   & P_{U,1} & P_{U,2} & \ldots & P_{U,B} \\
\end{array} \right]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    P =
    \kbordermatrix{%
           & BS_1    & BS_2    & \ldots & BS_B    \\
    UE_1   & P_{1,1} & P_{1,2} & \ldots & P_{1,B} \\
    UE_2   & P_{2,1} & P_{2,2} & \ldots & P_{1,B} \\
    \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
    UE_U   & P_{U,1} & P_{U,2} & \ldots & P_{U,B}
  }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have kbordermatrix but the [] in blkarray expand, not as far as in your array example as there they are expanding over the first line headers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some possibilities:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blkarray}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    P =
    \begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
               & BS_1    & BS_2    & \ldots & BS_B    \\ 
    \begin{block}{c[cccc]}
        UE_1   & P_{1,1} & P_{1,2} & \ldots & P_{1,B} \\
        UE_2   & P_{2,1} & P_{2,2} & \ldots & P_{1,B} \\
        \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
        UE_U   & P_{U,1} & P_{U,2} & \ldots & P_{U,B} \\
    \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    P = \left[
    \begin{array}{c|cccc}
               & BS_1    & BS_2    & \ldots & BS_B    \\ \hline
        UE_1   & P_{1,1} & P_{1,2} & \ldots & P_{1,B} \\
        UE_2   & P_{2,1} & P_{2,2} & \ldots & P_{1,B} \\
        \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
        UE_U   & P_{U,1} & P_{U,2} & \ldots & P_{U,B} \\
\end{array} \right]
\end{equation}



\vspace{15pt}
\begin{equation}
    P = \hspace{3.23em}\left[\hspace{-3.3em}
    \begin{array}{c@{\hspace{1em}}cccc}
\noalign{\vspace{-15pt}}
               & BS_1    & BS_2    & \ldots & BS_B    \\
\noalign{\vspace{2pt}}
        UE_1   & P_{1,1} & P_{1,2} & \ldots & P_{1,B} \\
        UE_2   & P_{2,1} & P_{2,2} & \ldots & P_{1,B} \\
        \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
        UE_U   & P_{U,1} & P_{U,2} & \ldots & P_{U,B} \\
\end{array} \right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

---

The delimiters fall short in `blkarray` as it locally sets `\delimtershortfall` and `\delimiterfactor` to make them do so. If you don't want that you can locally disable that feature:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blkarray}

\newdimen\zzzzdimen
\newcount\zzzzcount
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\let\delimitershortfall\zzzzdimen
\let\delimiterfactor\zzzzcount
    P =
    \begin{blockarray}{ccccc}
               & BS_1    & BS_2    & \ldots & BS_B    \\ 
    \begin{block}{c[cccc]}
        UE_1   & P_{1,1} & P_{1,2} & \ldots & P_{1,B} \\
        UE_2   & P_{2,1} & P_{2,2} & \ldots & P_{1,B} \\
        \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
        UE_U   & P_{U,1} & P_{U,2} & \ldots & P_{U,B} \\
    \end{block}
    \end{blockarray}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    P = \left[
    \begin{array}{c|cccc}
               & BS_1    & BS_2    & \ldots & BS_B    \\ \hline
        UE_1   & P_{1,1} & P_{1,2} & \ldots & P_{1,B} \\
        UE_2   & P_{2,1} & P_{2,2} & \ldots & P_{1,B} \\
        \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
        UE_U   & P_{U,1} & P_{U,2} & \ldots & P_{U,B} \\
\end{array} \right]
\end{equation}



\vspace{15pt}
\begin{equation}
    P = \hspace{3.23em}\left[\hspace{-3.3em}
    \begin{array}{c@{\hspace{1em}}cccc}
\noalign{\vspace{-15pt}}
               & BS_1    & BS_2    & \ldots & BS_B    \\
\noalign{\vspace{2pt}}
        UE_1   & P_{1,1} & P_{1,2} & \ldots & P_{1,B} \\
        UE_2   & P_{2,1} & P_{2,2} & \ldots & P_{1,B} \\
        \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
        UE_U   & P_{U,1} & P_{U,2} & \ldots & P_{U,B} \\
\end{array} \right]
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The thing is the `blkarray` environment does not expand `[]` as in the using the `\left[ \right]`. Since in my case `P_{U,B}` has the `{U,B}` lower part, the bracket does not cover it as in the `array` environment. The `kbordermatrix` look is similar to the `array` in that aspect but it does not provide consistency look inside the matrix, namely space between elements. I will some pictures.

Comment: @cacamailg: I don't see any difference in the "spacing between elements" inside the [`kbordermatrix`](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/LaTeX.shtml) environment. You *can* change the font size of the row/column indices.

Comment: @cacamailg blkarray is using \left\right to expand the `[]` around the blocks. since I haven't looked at the source for a decade or two I can't recall exactly how it chooses the size, I agree it could be a bit bigger but...

Comment: @Werner when I say "space between elements" I mean in comparison with the `array` package, which I am trying to follow.

Comment: @cacamailg: What I'm saying is that I see no difference in the "space between elements" when comparing `array` with `kbordermatrix`.

Comment: @cacamailg you haven't commented on the example (3) above, is that the outcome you want?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Somehow it is. My only concern is the hardcoded values for lengths. That is why I would prefer to use the `blkarray` with the "more" expanded `[]`.

Comment: @cacamailg see update

Comment: @cacamailg just beware I haven't touched blkarray sources since 1992 and the main part of its documentation is:  `%%%     A LaTeX style option extending array and tabular
%%%     HIGHLY VOLATILE, use at your own risk!!!!!!!!` :-)